# Is it possible to create a view using the EntityManager with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a project with Spring Data JPA. and I want to add some customized behavior to the repository.

At the moment I'm trying to create a view by executing the method

The repository class is as follows.

```
public interface MyQueryRepository extends JpaRepository<MyQuery, Long>, MyQueryRepositoryCustom {
    public MyQuery findById(long id);
    public list executeMyQuery();

}
```

This is the customization:

```
public class MyQueryRepositoryImpl implements MyQueryRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List executeMyQuery() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("CREATE VIEW result_set AS select record FROM my_data").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Howeve, I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ErrorCounter - line 1:1: unexpected token: CREATE
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: CREATE
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:198) [hibernate-core-5.1.1.Final.jar:5.1.1.Final]
```

The above code works for SELECT queries.

Is there any other way, that I could CREATE VIEW using entity managers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with `getResultList()`, you have to make **Select** and not CREATE? UPDATE? Or DELETE.

So if you want to CREATE a view then you have to execute your query, and not `getResultList()`, to create a view i suggest to use **CreateNativeQuery** for example :

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("CREATE VIEW result_set AS 
                                           select record FROM my_data");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Else if you want to get values from your query then you have to change your query to `SELECT something FROM result_set`